# jQuery doesn't load whole table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website with a table where I would like to update data periodically.

I have a script:

```
   <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
       setTimeout( function results() {
         $('.results').load("results.php?RES=1");
         setTimeout(results, 120000);
       }, 0000);
    })
    </script>
```

This runs when page is ready and then after every two minutes.

The response from results.php?RES=1 is following:

```
        <th colspan='7'>DS1</th>
<tr>

        <td>1</td>
        <td>02:02:48</td>
        <td>(1) Name</td>
        <td>TEAM</td>
        <td>ger</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
                    </tr><tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>00:47:49</td>
        <td>(99) Name</td>
        <td>TEAM</td>
        <td>EST</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
                    </tr>
```

The output should be inserted into here:

```
<div class="col col-md-5 px-5 pt-3" style="background-color:white;"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1 class="py-3">RESULTS</h1>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-sm table-striped" style="table-layout: fixed;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="5%">Place</th>
    <th width="10%">Time</th>
    <th width="30%">Name</th>
    <th width="15%">Team</th>
    <th width="10%">Country</th>
    <th width="20%" colspan="2"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="list results" id="results">
    ///***THE RESULTS SHOULD BE APPEAR HERE***///
                    </tbody>
</table>
</div>  

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Somehow only the last row of table appears. Why?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Try: $('#results') instead of $('.results')

Comment: Tried that, but it won't work

Comment: Have you errors in console?

Comment: No errors in console

Comment: The `<th>` element isn't wrapped in a `<tr>`

Comment: Check the response in the network tab or use `$.ajax()` to get the results and check the response and insert it "by hand"

Comment: Wrapping th with tr helped! Thanks Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working by wrapping `<th>` element with `<tr>`